# jQuery Concatenate format(string and conditional statement)

Tags: javascript, jquery

what I am trying to do is append a `<select>` tag and do an `if` statement.

I do have error. I think it's the way I am concatenating the string..

here's my code:

```
var load_volumes = jQuery('.micronic').val();
var arr_volumes = load_volumes.split(',');

var count_volumes = arr_volumes.length;
for(x=0; x<count_volumes; x++){

    jQuery('.append_here').append("<select class='volumes'>"
                                    +"<option>Choose Volume</option>"
                                    +"<option"
                                    + if(arr_volumes[x] == 0.5){
                                    + "selected"    
                                    + }
                                    +">0.5</option>"
                                    +"<option>0.75</option>"
                                    +"<option>1.10</option>"
                                    +"<option>1.40</option>"
                                    +"<option>2.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>2.5</option>"
                                    +"<option>3.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>4.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>6.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>7.5</option></select> &nbsp");
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: here's the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if` @PraveenKumar

Comment: You'd do well to add that crucial information to the question itself.

Comment: You are concatenating an if statement, which is an invalid markup

Comment: You can't have an `if` statement in the middle of a string like that

Comment: can you give an example sir?

Comment: Use the ternary operator instead of the if.

Comment: `+ (arr_volumes[x] == 0.5 ? "selected" : "")`

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem? If so, please select the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer below. You should consider using a template engine such as handlebars though.

```
jQuery('.append_here').append("<select class='volumes'>"
                                +"<option>Choose Volume</option>"
                                +"<option"
                                + (arr_volumes[x] == 0.5? " selected" : "")
                                +">0.5</option>"
                                +"<option>0.75</option>"
                                +"<option>1.10</option>"
                                +"<option>1.40</option>"
                                +"<option>2.0</option>"
                                +"<option>2.5</option>"
                                +"<option>3.0</option>"
                                +"<option>4.0</option>"
                                +"<option>6.0</option>"
                                +"<option>7.5</option></select> &nbsp");
```

Comment: the use of ternary if else is nice too.. thanks again. =)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line with `if` with ternary selector:

```
+ (arr_volumes[x] == 0.5? " selected" : "")
```

Answer (score 1):

The append function should have a single element as an input, but this would produce only warnings. The problem in your code is

```
+ if(arr_volumes[x] == 0.5){
+ "selected"    
+ }
```

Ideally set this value in advance. Your code could look something like this:

```
var volumes = (arr_volumes[x] == 0.5) ? " selected" : ""; 
var select = "<select class='volumes'>"
                            +"<option>Choose Volume</option>"
                            +"<option"
                            + volumes
                            +">0.5</option>"
                            +"<option>0.75</option>"
                            +"<option>1.10</option>"
                            +"<option>1.40</option>"
                            +"<option>2.0</option>"
                            +"<option>2.5</option>"
                            +"<option>3.0</option>"
                            +"<option>4.0</option>"
                            +"<option>6.0</option>"
                            +"<option>7.5</option></select> &nbsp";
jQuery('.append_here').append(select);
```

But consider something like this in the end to make it variable:

```
var values = [0.5, 0.75, 1.10, 1.40, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0, 6.0, 7.5];
var content = "<select class='volumes'>"
for(var i=0; values.length; i++) {
    content += "<option";
    content += (arr_volumes[x] == values[i]) ? " selected" : "";
    content += ">" + values[i] + "</option>";
}
content += "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to select

```
var s="";
if(arr_volumes[x] == 0.5){
         s=" selected "  ;
}

jQuery('.append_here').append("<select class='volumes'>"
                                    +"<option>Choose Volume</option>"
                                    +"<option"
                                    + s 
                                    +">0.5</option>"
                                    +"<option>0.75</option>"
                                    +"<option>1.10</option>"
                                    +"<option>1.40</option>"
                                    +"<option>2.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>2.5</option>"
                                    +"<option>3.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>4.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>6.0</option>"
                                    +"<option>7.5</option></select> &nbsp");
```

Comment: There is no space after `option` so string will be `optionselected`.